# Merging dataframes in in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a more efficient way to solve the below problem. I have 1 dataframe which consists of Account Numbers and its parent account. I have another dataframe (taken from a different database) which contains Account Numbers, Parent ID and Account Owner.

The idea is to join the Account Owner from the second dataframe to the first dataframe. While this should be straight forward i.e. doing a left join between both tables, I need to do 2 merges which seems very inefficient way of doing it.

The **first join** matches on the **account number** and maps the account owner, then the **2nd join** matches on the **parent account** and populates the account owner. In this example there are 2 rows containing 0 values, they will be left as is.

The reason for 2 checks - if an account doesn't have an owner, it then checks its parent account if it has an owner.

Here is my workings:

Dataframe 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5551455514,555145],
                    [9631475400,963147],
                    [1111111111,111111],
                    [2222222222,222222],
                    [8529875405,852987]],
columns = ['Account','ParentAccount'])
df
```

Dataframe 1 Output:

```
Account         ParentAccount
0   5551455514  555145
1   9631475400  963147
2   1111111111  111111          
3   2222222222  222222          
4   8529875405  852987
```

Dataframe 2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5551455514,555145,'Name_1'],
                    [9631475400,963147,'Name_2'],
                    [8529871478,852987,'Name_3']],
columns = ['Account','ParentAccount','Account Owner'])
df2
```

Dataframe 2 Output:

```
Account         ParentAccount   Account Owner
0   5551455514  555145          Name_1
1   9631475400  963147          Name_2
2   8529871478  852987          Name_3
```

Merging on the Account number, then merging on the parent account:

```
# left join on account as primary key between both dataframes
df = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on=['Account'], right_on=['Account'],how='left')
# left join on Parent ID as primary key between both dataframes
df = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on=['ParentAccount_x'], right_on=['ParentAccount'],how='left')

# Re-formatting.....
# drop Account column from dataframe 2 as it doesn't need to be include since account already exists in df1 
df = df.drop(['ParentAccount_y','Account Owner_x','ParentAccount','Account_y'], axis = 1)
# rename some headers
df.rename(columns = {'Account_x':'Account','ParentAccount_x':'ParentAccount','Account Owner_y':'Account Owner'}, inplace = True)
```

Output:

```
Account         ParentAccount   Account Owner
0   5551455514  555145          Name_1
1   9631475400  963147          Name_2
2   1111111111  111111          NaN
3   2222222222  222222          NaN
4   8529875405  852987          Name_3
```

There must be a better way to achieve the above output.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question asked yesterday see [How to deal with multiply merging between 2 Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71056053/how-to-deal-with-multiply-merging-between-2-dataframes).  Why are yoiu asking the same question again today?

Comment: No one seems to be able to solve the problem. In the above case, I have reduced some of my code so that it is easier to understand the problem I am trying to address or a better way to address it. I will be removing the url page you quote.

Comment: It would be better to edit your exiting question rather than having two open questions.

Comment: Also, why do you want the rows with 0 account, & 0 parentAccount values?

Comment: I had added them so that the final output still returns the original 5 rows of data with the merged data

Comment: Is that important

Comment: In my real data, there will be 100s of accounts that won't have an owner from the 2nd data source so they will return NaNs in these cases (which is okay) so i wanted to ensure the code always retains the original set of accounts.

Comment: I have changed the 0s to more meaningful values

Comment: You mentioned `The reason for 2 checks - if an account doesn't have an owner, it then checks its parent account if it has an owner.`, to see the logic behind, can you add only this row to your example df1: `[5551455599,555145]`, then only add this to your example df2: `[5551455544,555145,'Name_1a']`, and finally modify your expected output? In my extension, you will have a df1 row that doesn't have an account owner, but two owners under its parent account. You may reject this extension if it's impossible in your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Given your two data frames named df and df2 you can get the desired output by:

```
dk = pd.merge(df, df2, how='left', on='ParentAccount').drop(['Account_y'], axis= 1)
dk.rename(columns={'Account_x':'Account'}, inplace=True)
```

This yields:

```
    Account ParentAccount   Account Owner
0   5551455514  555145  Name_1
1   9631475400  963147  Name_2
2   1111111111  111111  NaN
3   2222222222  222222  NaN
4   8529875405  852987  Name_3
```